# Ruby on rails: Creating a model entry with a belongs_to association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, associations

I am trying to add a new entry in my database for a model that has a belongs_to relationship. I have 2 models, Jobs and Clients.

It was easy enough to find tutorial on how to set up the association between these two (using has_many and belongs_to), but I can't seem to find any examples where the association is actually used.

In my code, I am trying to create a new job for the first client. The jobs model has an attribute for client_id, and I know I can probably just manually fill the attribute, but there has to be some ruby convention to easily accomplish this.

```
Job.create(:client_id => 1, :subject => "Test", :description => "This is a test")
```

I can easily put that in my code, but I feel like ruby has a better way to do this. Here is the way my models are setup

```
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :actual_time, :assigned_at, :client_id, :completed_at, :estimated_time, :location, :responded_at, :runner_id, :status, :subject, :description
  belongs_to :client
end

class Client < User
    has_many :jobs
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :cell, :email, :pref

end
```

Comment: `client = Client.new;
Job.create(:client => client, :subject => "Test", :description => "This is a test")`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Just call `create` on the `jobs` collection of the client:

```
c = Client.find(1)
c.jobs.create(:subject => "Test", :description => "This is a test")
```

Comment: Bad, would raise an ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound if there is no entry with id=1 .... use `Client.find(:first)` or `Client.first`

Comment: @MrYoshiji raising an exception is usually the expected behavior since in rails `RecordNotFound` exceptions are translated into 404 requests in the exceptions app.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `create_job` in this way:

```
client = Client.create
job = client.create_job!(subject: 'Test', description: 'blabla')
```

When you declare a `belongs_to` association, the declaring class automatically gains five methods related to the association:

```
association
association=(associate)
build_association(attributes = {})
create_association(attributes = {})
create_association!(attributes = {})
```

In all of these methods, association is replaced with the symbol passed as the first argument to `belongs_to`.

more: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#belongs-to-association-reference

Comment: This would work if the association was belongs_to instead of has_many. Good to know,  but it doesn't address the issue.

Answer (score 4):

You can pass the object as argument to create the job:

```
client = Client.create
job = Job.create(client_id: client.id, subject: 'Test', description: 'blabla')
```

The `create` method will raise an error if the object is not valid to save (if you set validations like mandatory name, etc).

Comment: this only works if `client` is marked as `attribute_accessible`

Answer (score 3):

Pass the object itself as an argument, instead of passing its ID. That is, instead of passing `:client_id => 1` or `:client_id => client.id`, pass `:client => client`.

```rb
client = Client.find(1)
Job.create(:client => client, :subject => "Test", :description => "This is a test")
```

Answer (score -4):

For creating new instances you could use factories. For this you could simply use FactoryGirl https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl

So after you have defined your factory soewhat like this:

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :job do
    client FactoryGirl.create(:client)
    subject 'Test'
    description 'This is a Test'

You could then call FactoryGirl.create(:job) to generate a new job like that.
You could also call FactoryGirl.build(:job, client: aClientYouInstantiatedBefore, subject: 'AnotherTest') and also overwrite any other attributes

Factores are good if you want to create many objects, that are similar in a certain way.

Comment: Nowhere in his question, he mentioned that he wants to do it for specs.

Comment: you can use factories anywhere not only in specs or tests

Comment: if you're using factory girl for development you're doing it wrong.

Comment: @MentholBonbon you're right that `Factories are good if you want to create many objects, that are similar in a certain way`...that's the design pattern definition. But FactoryGirl, despite the name, is for testing.

Comment: You could use it in `group: development`, but only for creating stuff in the console quickly. It should never be in the gemfile's production group, or comitted in any part of your models/controllers/views.