# Rails associations has_many through: uninitialized constant error Should be easy answer: Am beginner

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

The models `BarberShop (table barber_shops)` and `Barber (table barbers)` all exist. In `rails c` after

```
x = Barber.new and x.include? :barbershop => true.
```

So the association should be set up correctly. When I try to save I get the

> **Name error Uninitialized constant BarberShop::Barber**.

I know it is something more than likely easy that I am having trouble finding. For example I learned today with a `has-many-through-association` the order (in the model) of the associations matter where a must be listed to get b - i.e.

```
has_many :a 
has_many :b, through: :a
```

The models are as below -

```
Barber < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :barbershop
  has_many :appointments 
  has_many :customers, through: :appointments


BarberShop < ApplicationRecord 
    has_many :barbers
end 
#schema in db
create_table "barber_shops", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
  end

  create_table "barbers", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.string "email"
    t.integer "barbershop_id", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.index ["barbershop_id"], name: "index_barbers_on_barbershop_id"
  end
```

Comment: updated table still does not work ```class     create_table :barbers do |t|
      t.string :name
  
      t.references :barbershop
 ```

Comment: Where is the code you are using to save?

Comment: ```> x
 => #<BarberShop id: nil, name: "shop",>
 > x.save
  BarberShop Create (3.0ms)  INSERT INTO "barber_shops" commit transaction
 => true
2.6.1 :006 > x
 => #<BarberShop id: 2, name: "shop">
2.6.1 :007 > y
2.6.1 :008 > y.barbershop_id = 2
 => 2
2.6.1 :009 > y
 => #<Barber name: "barber", barbershop_id: 2: nil>
2.6.1 :010 > y.save
NameError (uninitialized constant Barber::Barbershop):
        2::11
        1::11:in `rescue in irb_binding'
NameError (uninitialized constant Barber::Barbershop)
 > y.barbershop_id
 => 2```

Comment: if above is TL;DR status ```y.save
Traceback (most recent call last):
        1: from (irb):17
NameError (uninitialized constant Barber::Barbershop)``` where y is a barber.new with a name and barbershop_id. This error is unusual to me. I don't know what to do and i believe it is how my associations are established. I could be incorrect.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ruby on rails: Creating a model entry with a belongs\_to association](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16286944/ruby-on-rails-creating-a-model-entry-with-a-belongs-to-association)

Answer (score 0):

In a Rails app, the model `BarberShop` needs to be in the file `app/models/barber_shop.rb` and the model `Barber` needs to be in the file `app/model/barber.rb`.

If you don't name the files correctly, you can get odd behaviour because objects don't autoload as they should.

Comment: I used a generator so both are in that location and named properly.